# NASM 2 lines of db (initialized data) seemingly not working

Tags: nasm, x86-64

I have the following x86-64 code, which I can run on OSX Yosemite:

```
global _main
extern _exit
extern _puts

DEFAULT REL

section .data

putsmsg:    db      'Puts message...',0
another:    db      0

section .text

_main:
    push        rbp
    mov         rbp, rsp

    ; print a string using PUTS
    lea         rdi, [putsmsg]
    call        _puts

    ; call EXIT(0) c function
    mov         rdi, 0
    call        _exit
```

I compile, link, and run as follows (where the source is a.asm):

```
nasm -f macho64 a.asm ; gcc a.o -o a.bin ;./a.bin
```

It does not print the message 'Puts message...', whereas it does print the message if I simply comment out the line containing the label 'another'. What is going wrong here? Why doesn't it print the correct string when I have the other initialized data line?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. Try returning from `main` instead of calling `exit`... though `exit` should flush all open streams anyway. Anyhow, works for me on Linux.

Comment: In case it's relevant: NASM version 2.11.08 compiled on Mar 10 2015. Installed with homebrew on my 15" macbook pro retina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me on GNU/Linux, with yasm.  (After removing the `_` prefix from function names.)

```
$ yasm -felf64 puts.asm
$ gcc -o put puts.o
$ ./puts
Puts message...
```

That's with the 2nd db line still present:

```
another:    db      0
```

There was another question about almost exactly this problem (a message not printing when there was more data following the string) on OS X, within the past couple weeks.  The OP of that question found that yasm on OS X worked for him.  Maybe there's a bug in nasm for OS X?

I eventually found the post I was talking about: [Position Independent Code pointing to wrong address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31640418/224132).  See the discussion in comments on my answer.  The OP found his code worked with yasm, but wasn't able to tell if there was a bug in nasm or if he was just using it wrong.

Comment: I tried having multiple lines of db, without labels, and this works as expected. It's simply the addition of an additional label that seems to break it.

Comment: Have you looked at the memory in a debugger?  Like, stop before the call to `puts`, and in gdb  `x /20c <value or rdi>`  (just copy/paste the value from the `layout reg` area).  If you don't see your string, with a zero-byte at the end, then there's a problem.

Comment: The above code works if I change .data to .text, but this seems like a suboptimal solution... I'll try looking at the program with a debugger, but I'll first have to learn some basic debugging.

Comment: @bean: I searched my comment history and finally found the post.  I guess SO and google search don't see buried comments.

Comment: @bean: you do actually want your read-only data in the `.text` (or `.rodata`) section.  It's read-only, so it can be in memory pages that are mapped read-only and shared between multiple instances of the library or executable.

Comment: @bean: for debugging, gdb with `layout asm`, `layout reg` is pretty good.  `edb` looks great, except it you have to manually dump a symbol table from an executable, and then load it, so it's kinda bad for a compile/debug/edit cycle.  There are some links and info at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Single-stepping in asm and watching registers change is a great way to learn.

Comment: So, all of the data is there in the .data section, as one would hope it would be. The problem is the values assigned to the labels. From the code in the question statement, the value of 'putsmsg' is 256 too high, whereas the value of 'another' is correct. If I have a bunch of db or resb statements, only the last one is correct (unless the ones before last are resb 0). Sounds like NASM bug?

Comment: @bean: yeah sounds that way.  http://www.nasm.us/ points to their bug-tracker at http://bugzilla.nasm.us/